# Should I filter data in PostgreSQL or server backend?

Tags: postgresql, graphql

I am working on a project which uses graphql and PostgreSQL where we want to select data from the database with a value after a certain date. It is currently selecting all data from the database and then filtering it on the server:

```
.filter(({time}) => moment(time).isAfter(startTime))
```

However I would have thought it would be best to do this filtering in the database query as the full dataset is never used.

Is there any benefit to doing it on the server rather than in the database query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barring some unusual edge case -- such as other parts of your backend code really do need all the data for some reason -- it would definitely be more efficient to filter everything on the *Postgres* side via the *SQL* that is being used to fetch the data in the first place.

This is true for several reasons:

1. Assuming the table is properly indexed, the filtering will be able to occur much faster within the database.
2. The unneeded data will not need to be serialized and sent over the wire to the backend, only to then be discarded by the backend's own filtering.
3. The memory footprint should be reduced on both the Postgres and server end due to needing to process only a portion of the results.

I've not worked with *GraphQL* myself, but from doing a bit of poking around through its docs, it appears *GraphQL* often uses other mechanisms in different layers (outside of the database) to try to improve performance.

It would be worth seeing what the actual SQL is that your *GraphQL* query is generating (that may be possible via a function in *GraphQL*; it could also be done by enabling certain log settings on the Postgres server and correlating the log output to the query). That may lead to further optimization possibilities if you want to keep things purely *GraphQL*.

Jumping down to a raw query seems like it would be a good possibility though. Certainly that is something that is often done with ORMs like *Django* and *ActiveRecord*.